# How to remove quotes from property in Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to Serialize the object to json string and it's look like

```
    [
  {
    "Key": "Products",
    "Items": [
      {
        "name": "ProductID",
        "iskey": true,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "green"
      },
      {
        "name": "ProductName",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Cube",
        "color": "bluegrad"
      },
      {
        "name": "SupplierID",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "purple"
      },
      {
        "name": "CategoryID",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "purple"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "Suppliers",
    "Items": [
      {
        "name": "SupplierID",
        "iskey": true,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "green"
      },
      {
        "name": "CompanyName",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Cube",
        "color": "bluegrad"
      },
      {
        "name": "ContractName",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "purple"
      },
      {
        "name": "Address",
        "iskey": false,
        "figure": "Decision",
        "color": "purple"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

if you look into the json my property also contains the quotes like **"name"** I want only name in json string how can I do this, my code look likes

```
 var jj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodeDataArray,Formatting.Indented);
```

where nodeDataArray Contains the Data

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? By not having quotes around your key values, you're invalidating your JSON.

Comment: from [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf):_An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs.
A name is a string._ so property name **should be** string, and also quotes must have

Comment: I think it is perfectly valid to not have quotes around keys, I know it because we use it in our project. @dhaval - if you're flexible to use another library you could try ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer. I don't have link to it right now. But it works well. We get serialized json string like "[{Key:Products,Items:[{name:ProductID,iskey: true}]}]" but no indentation.

Comment: @aSharma The fact that **you think** it's perfectly valid doesn't make it so. It's not JSON anymore if there aren't quotes around the property names. That aside, there can be perfectly valid **reasons** to do this and people are curious why. They're just comments. And the latter half of your own comment looks like an answer. You should post a well-written version of that, including how to accomplish it. =)

Comment: OK, sorry for confusion here. I meant object serialized as 'json string' not 'json object'. I cannot edit the previous comment now.

Comment: some json parsers are, correctly, forgiving of invalid input (e.g. missing quotes around property names).  That doesn't mean the json is valid.  JSON must have quotes around property names to be valid.